# SSRS 2016 Reports migration Issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, migration

Issue: after upgrading the SSRS to 2016, Reports are not accessible and it is giving error.

First it is giving the error 1:

> Login failed for User ‘NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’

after that I restored the encryption key then

Later it is giving the error below:

> Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RdlHelper, Version=7.0.0.0,
>   ulture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (rsErrorLoadingExprHostAssembly)

Brief description about Issue :

- We have migrated the SQL 2012 to SQL 2016 by copy cluster role wizard, then I have installed the SQL 2016 cluster in DB Cluster later restored the databases.
- For SSRS we have other Virtual machine,  then we perform the version upgrade in SSRS VM after that I restored the Encryption Key, even though Issue is not resolved.

Sir, Please let me know is the Issue is related to MS CRM or SSRS, if its related to SSRS , could you please provide me your time slot and your charges to resolve the Issue.

Comment: Someone gave you an answer.  Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is somewhat similar to what I faced earlier this year.

Below link might help you deal with issue and probably will give a solution.

http://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/rdl-file-is-not-valid/

Do let me know if this helps.